# CSS: Blurring the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this :

```html
<div class="customer">
  <div [ngSwitch]="accessLevel">
    <div class="customer" *ngSwitchCase="'ENABLED'">
      <h2 class="label">Customer</h2><br>
      <span>{{customerData.oldId}}</span><br>
      <span>{{customerData.firstName}}</span><br>
      <span>{{customerData.lastName}}</span><br>
      <span>{{customerData.addressLine1}}</span><br>
      <span>{{customerData.email}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="customer-blurr" *ngSwitchCase="'DISABLED'"></div>
    <div class="customer-blurr" *ngSwitchDefault></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in CSS:

```css
.customer {
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
  height: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
}
.customer-blurr {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
  height: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

When the condition **Disabled is true** I want my div to be blurred and it works as well but the dimensions/size are different. Please see the attached images to see the size difference to the tab's width.

Please help me with this.

Thanks

[![blurred][1]][1]
[![Active][3]][3]

Comment: use .customer[disabled=disabled] and toggle the disabled attribute

Comment: @D_Supreme where should i use it ? would be great if you could give me a bit more details . Thanks

Comment: is it possible to have only one div ? which uses .customer class and ngSwitchCase toggles the disabled property. then use the above mentioned class

Comment: @D_Supreme, yes it is possible, with different div's i was just trying to achieve: if enabled then user can see, and if not then he should not see anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your HTML like this

```html
<div class="customer">
  <div [ngSwitch]="accessLevel">
    <div class="customer" disabled = "{ return *ngSwitchCase }">
      <h2 class="label">Customer</h2><br>
      <span>{{customerData.oldId}}</span><br>
      <span>{{customerData.firstName}}</span><br>
      <span>{{customerData.lastName}}</span><br>
      <span>{{customerData.addressLine1}}</span><br>
      <span>{{customerData.email}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="customer-blurr" *ngSwitchDefault></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS as:

```css
.customer {
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
  height: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
}
.customer[disabled=disabled] {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 27%;
  height: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px;
}
```